# How to Parse using Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How can I parse this type of string

```
"POST /trusted HTTP/1.1" "000.00.00.0" 200 9 "42" 123456 A3rTW6ecEIcBACvMEbAACAJA
```

Using Regex?

My desired output is

- `POST /trusted HTTP/1.1`
- `000.00.00.0`
- `200`
- `9`
- `42`
- `123456`
- `A3rTW6ecEIcBACvMEbAACAJA`

Comment: seems to me that you can simply just split the string at each space and then recombine the first three elements again as the rest are simply separated by a space...

Comment: What makes you think that regex is the tool for this? What have you tried?

Comment: I am using  @"""[^""\r\n]*""|\s""[^""\r\n]*""|\s[\d]*"..but not getting proper o/p

Comment: I am using @"""[^""\r\n]*""|\s""[^""\r\n]*""|\s[\d]*"..but not getting proper o/p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
   string input =@"""POST /trusted HTTP/1.1"" ""000.00.00.0"" 200 9 ""42"" 123456 A3rTW6ecEIcBACvMEbAACAJA"; 
   var r = 
        Regex.Matches(
            input,
            "((\"[^\"]+\")|([^\" ]+))"
        );
    foreach (var s in r)
    {
      System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }           

    System.Console.ReadLine();
```